# I am below you, and I help you; what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am below you, and I help you.
>
> Some people seem to hate me, most neglect me.
>
> My greatest ally is my lover, who cheats on me for you right now.
>
> You caress me now.

What am I?

Comment: @Bhansa If you think that you have the answer, please post it as an answer, not as a comment. It ruins the fun for people who want to figure the answer out for themselves.

Comment: Sorry deleted, btw this was my first comment, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What am I?

> The computer keyboard

I am below you, and I help you.

> The keyboard is below the screen, and therefore below the user's head. 
> The keyboard helps the user use the computer.

Some people seem to hate me, most neglect me.

> Ever since those Xerox PARC guys went and got creative,
> everybody loves the GUI, and some people hate the CLI.

My greatest ally is my lover, who cheats on me for you right now.

> The ally/lover is the computer mouse (or other pointing device),
> which goes hand-in-hand (no pun intended) with the keyboard. 
> But, as mentioned in the previous paragraph,
> some/many people prefer the GUI over the CLI,
> and, accordingly, prefer the pointing device over the keyboard.
> Thus, the mouse consorts with the user,
> to the (possible) exclusion of the keyboard.

You caress me now.

> If you're accessing Stack Exchange, you're probably using a computer. 
> Even if you aren't typing, your hands are probably touching the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer should be

> `ground`

As it is below us and it helps us to walk.

Some people may hate it, and most even neglect its significance.

> My greatest ally is my lover

which should be

> **`sky`**

*who cheats on me for you right now*

Sky is always above us.

> you caress me now

We caress the surface, the ground with our feet.

Comment: Great answer, but it's not very close.